# Carbon error Trailing data after laravel update

Tags: php, laravel

After updating laravel from 5.3 to 5.5 . I have Carbon error

```
InvalidArgumentException
Trailing data
```

But I dont even using Carbon In project . Im using it in one Controller . But deleted code and still getting error .

Here http://prntscr.com/qs4vcp error

Solution: In my 'users' table's created_at column had restriction for only 6 character . I deleted it and all works .

Comment: Can you please explain the issue by showing the code in detail at which action you are getting the error so that will be easy to identify it.

Comment: @SohilChamadia When I try to login I getting error .I think It is in LoginController .

Comment: Please show the code of it as well as model file code.

Comment: @SohilChamadia Thanks I solved it .

Answer (score 0):

Solution: In my 'users' table's created_at column had restriction for only 6 character. I deleted it and all works.

*answered by @JKSDS*